# How to get the first 5 elements from a queue c++

Tags: c++

How can I get the first five elements from a queue without using `for` loop?

Comment: use a while loop <g>

Comment: Why do you not want to use a loop here?

Comment: homework, surely? What else imposes a limitation like that...

Answer (score 5):

No explicit loops at all:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
class QueuePopper
{
public:
    QueuePopper(std::queue<T> &q) : q(q) {}
    T operator() (const T &) { T t = q.front(); q.pop(); return t; }
private:
    std::queue<T> &q;
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::string T;

    std::queue<T> q;

    ...

    std::vector<T> v(5);
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), QueuePopper<T>(q));
}
```

Comment: in this solution is hidden loop exist in `transform`, then where is border of your loop hiding? I can export function with loop to other file and this is a same.

Comment: @Svisstack:  Of course.  This is an artificial scenario!  But I haven't had to actually *write* a loop.

Answer (score 4):

One more way:

```
template<int n> void GetElements(queue<string>& qu)
{
    if(!qu.empty())
    {
        cout << qu.front() << '\n';
        qu.pop();
    }
    GetElements<n-1>(qu);
}

template<> void GetElements<0>(queue<string>& qu) {}

// and call:
GetElements<5>(qu);
```

Or:

```
switch(qu.size())
{
default: cout << qu.front() << '\n'; qu.pop();
case 4: cout << qu.front() << '\n'; qu.pop();
case 3: cout << qu.front() << '\n'; qu.pop();
case 2: cout << qu.front() << '\n'; qu.pop();
case 1: cout << qu.front() << '\n'; qu.pop();
case 0: ;
}
```

Comment: +1, because each time I see it, i find that the second construct is really clever.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that?  Maybe you have to hold 5 elements in hand at a time fr reasons that are not clear here.

Anyway - if you means STL `<queue>`:

```
std::queue<Element> container;

Element e1, e2, e3, e3, e5;

e1 = container.front();
container.pop();
e2 = container.front();
container.pop();
e3 = container.front();
container.pop();
e4 = container.front();
container.pop();
e5 = container.front();
container.pop();
```

Behaviour is undefined if < 5 elements on the `queue`.

You can replace this with the below if you want to avoid the `Element` copy, however in this case be aware that the reference becomes invalid after the referenced element is popped.

```
std::queue<Element> container;

Element& e1 = container.front();    // or const Element&
container.pop();
Element& e2 = container.front();
container.pop();
Element& e3 = container.front();
container.pop();
Element& e4 = container.front();
container.pop();
Element& e5 = container.front();
container.pop();
```

Comment: That code doesn’t work. Declaring `e1` as a reference means you need to initialize it right away.

Comment: I would think you would want to copy.  What are you referring to after the pop()?

Comment: @stefaanv - agreed, but the requirement in the q appears to be artificial anyway...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

int main(){
    std::queue<std::string> q;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; ++i){
        std::string s;
        std::cin >> s;
        q.push(s);
    }
    int itemsToFetch = 5;
    do{
        std::string curString = q.front();
        q.pop();
        std::cout << curString << std::endl;
        --itemsToFetch;
    } while (itemsToFetch > 0 && !q.empty());
    return 0;
}
```